# How to reflect (or mirror) a point cloud in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization, static-transform-publisher, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have successfully set-up ros so that a point cloud is sent to rviz every 100ms. It looks great, however, the visualization is mirrored about the z-y axis.

I have already tried using static_transform_publisher (http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher), but this only allows me to rotate or translate. Is there a way to reflect/mirror about an axis using static_transform_publisher?

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287748/how-to-reflect-(or-mirror)-a-point-cloud-in-rviz-?/) by [super248](https://answers.ros.org/users/34517/super248/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-04-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-04-06**:
A generic open source point cloud scaling node/let could be useful for other people (or does it already exist?)- every axis could have a scale factor that could also be negative, allowing for mirroring and other uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could look at fixing the mirroring upstream- in whatever is generating the point cloud, or create a node that subscribes to your mirrored point cloud and flips each point as needed then republishes, look at http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#Subscribing_to_point_clouds for the starting point.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0